# Python: Building a dependency graph from items in a List

Tags: python, python-2.7

I would like to b build a data dependency graph between items in a list (assembly instruction). Here is what i'm looking for:

I have to extract the operands from 3 consecutive assembly instructions into a LIST and find if there is a data dependency. consider for eg 3 instructions:

```
[add1 a1, a2, a3] (Format: instruction dest, source, source)
[sub a4, a5, a1]
[add2 a6, a4, a1]
```

Here sub instruction depends on result of add1 instruction. Similarly, add2 instruction depends on result of both add1 and sub. My output should detect and report these two (2->1 and 3-> 1,2). I'm thinking on 2 approaches:

Approach 1: extract result operand of 1 and compare with source operands of instruction 2 and 3 n then extract result operand of 2 and compare with source operands of instruction 3.

Approach 2: Build a tree with source operands as child nodes and dest as root and check if nodes are interconnected

I tried approach 1, but was wondering how this can be achieved using approach 2.

Comment: Not entirely sure if the `assembly` tag is relevant here, since you're not actually programming in assembly; the root problem is dealing with complex dependencies.

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/toposort/1.0 ?

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham: I'm not sure on the approach 2. The approach 1, where I compare each operands with every other operand doesn't quite work well because of the variation in the number of operands for each instruction and redundant comparison. There are instances where I need to know the dependency between instructions which are separated by 4-5 other instructions (I'm restricting my dependency search to a sequence of 5 instructions maximum) . Is there a better approach?

Answer (score -1):

Translating the instructions to [SSA form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSA_(compilers)) can help a lot with this and many optimizations based around constructing this sort of graph. Moreover, intuitively I don't think you're guaranteed to get a [DAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) tree without doing so.

Comment: I'm not sure on the approach 2. The approach 1, where I compare each operands with every other operand doesn't quite work well because of the variation in the number of operands for each instruction and redundant comparison. There are instances where I need to know the dependency between instructions which are separated by 4-5 other instructions between. Is there a better approach?